# What are the steps to factorize a quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to factorize for example $x^2 + 15x + 36 = 0$ into $(x+3)(x+12)=0.$

Undoing the factorization is easy, but what is the "forward" algorithm?

Comment: Factor $36$ and find the two factors which sum to $15$

Comment: you can tell whether it does factor at all:  for $ax^2 + bxy+cy^2,$ find the discriminant $D = b^2 - 4ac.$  If $D$ is a perfect square, the thing factors. Here $15^2 - 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 36 = 225 - 144 = 81 = 9^2  $

Answer (score 3):

What @Mason said is the best way of thinking about it:

if you have the polynomial $x^2 + bx + c$, then to factor it you need to find two numbers, let's call them $p$ and $q$, where $pq = c$ and $p+q = b$. Then your factorized polynomial will look like $(x+p)(x+q)$.

In this example, we have $x^2 + 15x + 36$, so we need to find $p,q$ such that $pq = 36$ and $p+q=15$. The solution to these equations is $p=12,q=3$ (or $p=3,q=12$), so the factorized polynomial is $$x^2 + 15x + 36 = (x+3)(x+12).$$

Comment: This method is typically called the "sum and product" technique. Given $p=12,q=3$, the trick is to split the degree $1$ term and factor: $$x^2+15x+36=x^2+3x+12x+36=x(x+3)+12(x+3)=(x+3)(x+12)$$

Answer (score 0):

If we have a polynomial $x^2 + bx + c$ and its factored form is $(x + d)(x + k)$, we know that $d + k = b$ and $dk = c$. Using this algorithm for an equation such as $x^2 + 7x + 12$, we know that $dk = 12$ and $d + k$ is 7, so we find the values of $d$ and $k$ where this holds true. We can solve this using simultaneous equations $(d + k = 7 \implies d = 7 - k$, plugging this value of $d$ into $dk = 12$ gives us $(7 - k)k$ or $7k - k^2 = 12$ then we just use the quadratic formula to solve this and get $k = 4$ or 3, the other value is the value of $d$ or whatever other variable you have) or we can just look at the factors of 12 (1 & 12, 2 & 6, 3 & 4) and once we see which adds to 7, we get our answer for the values of $d$ and $k$, in this case 3 and 4.

Comment: Why are you using MathJax for some and not for others? Seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: Sorry, still very new to MathJax and haven't had much time to learn it recently. When I have learnt it up to the point where I can fix, I will fix it, sorry again.

Comment: All you have to do is surround all the "math" with dollar signs.

Comment: You have no idea how much this actually helped. Tysm.